# Scaled image blurry in PDFBox

Tags: java, image-processing, pdfbox

I'm trying to scaling an image with size = 2496 x 3512 into a PDF document. I'm using PDFBox to generate it but the scaled image ends up blurred.

Here are some snippets:

- PDF Page size (A4) returned by page.findMediaBox().createDimension(): java.awt.Dimension[width=612,height=792]
- Then I calculate the scaled dimension based on the Page size vs. Image size which returns: java.awt.Dimension[width=562,height=792]
  I use the code below in order to calculate the scaled dimension:

  ```
  public static Dimension getScaledDimension(Dimension imgSize, Dimension boundary) {
    int original_width = imgSize.width;
    int original_height = imgSize.height;
    int bound_width = boundary.width;
    int bound_height = boundary.height;
    int new_width = original_width;
    int new_height = original_height;

    // first check if we need to scale width
    if (original_width > bound_width) {
      //scale width to fit
      new_width = bound_width;
      //scale height to maintain aspect ratio
      new_height = (new_width * original_height) / original_width;
    }

    // then check if we need to scale even with the new height
    if (new_height > bound_height) {
      //scale height to fit instead
      new_height = bound_height;
      //scale width to maintain aspect ratio
      new_width = (new_height * original_width) / original_height;
    }

    return new Dimension(new_width, new_height);
  }
  ```
- And to actually perform the image scaling I'm using Image Scalr API:

  ```
  BufferedImage newImg = Scalr.resize(img, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT, 
    scaledWidth, scaledHeight, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
  ```

My question is what am I doing wrong? A big image shouldn't be blurred when scaled to a smaller size. Is this something related to the PDF page resolution/size?

Thank you,

Gyo

Comment: *what am I doing wrong?* - You are mistaking the units of the dimensions for pixel sizes. Instead, those units merely are units in a coordinate system (1/72 in by default) and may encompass multiple pixels on the display or printout. As you found out yourself, you had best include the image as is and only tell PDFBox the area in which to display it.

Comment: Yes, after searching for similar threads I ended up finding out the discrepancy between the dimensions. So let's PDFBox do the magic. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Ok, I found a way to add images without losing the quality.

Actually to make the image not be blurred I let PDFBox to resize the image by giving it the desired size. Like the code below:

```
PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDJpeg(doc, new FileInputStream(new File("/usr/gyo/my_large_image.jpg")), 1.0f);
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, false);
Dimension scaledDim = getScaledDimension(new Dimension(ximage.getWidth(),  ximage.getHeight()), page.getMediaBox().createDimension());
contentStream.drawXObject(ximage, 1, 1, scaledDim.width, scaledDim.height);
contentStream.close();
```

Thank you,

Gyo

Comment: Indeed, let PDFBox do it. The advantage of this strategy is that the image will look better at a high resolution. Btw, PDJpeg has a constructor that accepts a stream.

Comment: Hi Tilman. I'll take a look at the constructor then. I need to be sure it uses similar ImageIO method to load images. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, if possible, please change your answer so that it uses a stream, so that stackoverflow has the "best possible answer" to your question. new PDJpeg(doc, new FileInputStream(new File(...)));

Comment: @GyowannyPessattoQueiroz.. It worked fine for high resolution images. its fit to page but in case of small size image its not working properly . Small image is going in blur mode. can you please suggest me what we can do for any size of image will fit to page.

Comment: Are you trying to stretch a small image?

Comment: This is also great for not-too-big images. I've got a simple logo and I had lots of problems using different image processing techniques. Finally I found your post and - the logo looks great, thanks for sharing!